# How can I make Nautilus open with an extra panel by default?

Tags: nautilus

I would like to know how I can have an extra pane (press F3) in the file manager by default.

Currently, I add extra pane and when I close the File Manager, I have to add it again.

It's a shortcut away but I feel more productive when I have it and I don't think of adding it systematically.

Comment: I believe you would have to report a bug on Nautilus, because as far as I know, this is not a feature that Nautilus has :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For 12.04 / 12.10

I will use the `vim` editor, but if you don't know it, feel free to replace `vim` by `nano` (easy terminal editor) or `gedit` (gui editor).

**Installing xdotool**
You can install `xdotool` via the software center: [xdotool [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool).

or via

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

**Creating a custom script to launch nautilus**
Create a script with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash
nautilus $1 && sleep 0.5 ; xdotool key --clearmodifiers F3
```

and save it somewhere, let's assume we save it as `~/scripts/nautilus.bash`

Make the script executable with `chmod +x ~/scripts/nautilus.bash`.
Now test the script, typing `scripts/nautilus.bash` should open nautilus, and after a split second you should get your extra pane.

**Modifying the desktop file**
The desktop file of an application determines how your application will show up in the Unity launcher and dash, and what happens when you click on it.

You can use locate to find out its location

```
locate nautilus.desktop
```

This will return

```
/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Now to make sure nothing bad happens let's back it up:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop.bak
```

Now we can safely edit it (remember to use `gedit` or `nano` if you don't know `vim`):

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Now you will see the following (I removed some content in the middle)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nautilus %U
...

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=nautilus
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

We're interested in the `Exec=` lines, these lines determine what happens when we click the application. We need to change both (the one under `[Desktop Action Window]` is the entry in the Unity quicklist).

Now replace `nautilus` in the `Exec=` line by the location of your script, in my case `/home/gerhard/scripts/nautilus.bash` (The `%U` in the top one should stay). Now save and exit.

**Test it**
If you had nautilus locked to your launcher it will have disappeared, search in the Dash for 'Files' and clicking it should open nautilus with an extra pane!

---

**Notes**
If it works only sometimes (or not at all), maybe increase the time it waits before doing the keypress by increasing the value for the `sleep` function in your script.

Comment: i thank you for you answer,it is a great answer but as i specified in the question i don't want to use xdotool as a solution/workaround..

Comment: i'd rather find a native solution.. or hack into the source code or a fork or even use nemo if it has the functionality or at least its devs are open to implementing the option... also.. yes i know how to use vim and no i dont use emacs :)

Comment: don't get me wrong.. the xdotool workaround is an elegant solution.. just not the one i'd want to use at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
nautilus && sleep 0.5 ; xdotool key --clearmodifiers F3
```

You have to install `xdotool` first.

Comment: Probably takes quite a bit longer than pressing F3...

Answer (score 1):

I found somewhat I needed more elaborate use of xdotool.  While I was at it I decided a script taking an optional second directory argument for the new panel might be useful:

```
if  [ ! -d "$1" ];  then
 echo "parameter 1 not a directory"
 exit 1
fi 

theSubDir=${1##/*/}   #Deletes /*/ from front of $1, giving nautilus window title
file_browser_id=$(xdotool search --name "$theSubDir" | head -1)

if [ -n  "$file_browser_id" ]; then     # nautilus already open in directory
 exit 
fi 

nautilus "$1"
sleep 0.5
file_browser_id=$(xdotool search --name "$theSubDir" | head -1)

if [ -z  "$file_browser_id" ]; then
  echo no nautilus
  exit 
fi 

xdotool search --name "$theSubDir" windowactivate --sync key --window 0 F3

if [ $# -gt 1 ];  then 

 if  [ ! -d "$2" ];  then
  echo "source parameter not a directory"
  exit 1
 fi 

 xdotool search --name "$theSubDir" windowactivate --sync \ 
   key --window 0 --clearmodifiers Ctrl+l # location bar to path
 xdotool search --name "$theSubDir" windowactivate --sync type "$2" 
 xdotool search --name "$theSubDir" windowactivate --sync \
   key --window 0 --clearmodifiers Ctrl+l Return 
fi
```