# is it possible to make nautilus open with two panes by default?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus, filemanager, function-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make Nautilus open with a extra panel by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39004/how-can-i-make-nautilus-open-with-a-extra-panel-by-default)

Other than usign xdotool to send F3 to nautilus when it starts. 
(which is a solution..)

I'm wondering if anything new as been included in the nautilus codebase that enable it in preferences to open up dual paned by default.

I really liked total commander when using windows.. and other than to running it in wine, i haven't found any other more linux native way to manage more intuitively files and folders. (in a gui context)

Having two panes open up that remember where i was  prior to closing nautilus would be awesome if someone knows how enable it..

Comment: i don't think it's a duplicate.. since the other question as the answer below for an answer.. but since 11.10 or 12.04 the option isn't available anymore.. 
the other question was asked in may '11 so the user was most probably still using a version prior to 11.10 so his answer would be different..
also.. gnome was still at version 2.x .. not 3.x like now.. so another difference from the other question.. different context..
also.. the other question could be improved into writing  Nautilus instead of just File Manager in its question.. i probably never saw it for that fact alone..