# Force Nautilus to open with extra pane

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set extra pane as default in File Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39004/how-do-i-set-extra-pane-as-default-in-file-manager)

I've found having the extra pane in Nautilus (by clicking `F3`) to be insanely useful, and I'd like the extra pane to be open by default any time I open a nautilus window.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, No.
See the answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39004/how-do-i-set-extra-pane-as-default-in-file-manager)
And [Here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1435333)